# Not able to insert data into solr4.3 using this java code

Tags: java, solrj, solr4

My java code looks something like this:

```
public class CreateSolr4Doc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int recordCount = 3;
        CreateSolr4Doc instance = new CreateSolr4Doc();
        instance.createDummyData(recordCount);
    }

    private void createDummyData(int recordCount) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1";
        System.out.println(url);
        HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(url);
        for (int index = 0; index < recordCount; index++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=20000;j++)
            {
            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();   
              Date date = new Date();
              
              doc.addField("id","ibsfdjkhfb"+index+j);
              doc.addField("mongoid", "4eebb9db43d7391c16509153");
              doc.addField("agency","AFP");
              doc.addField("title","Masked men loot cash, cellphones"+(index+1));
              doc.addField("story",(index+1) + "PATNA: Giving a damn to");
              doc.addField("mimetype","TEXT");
              doc.addField("subject","The criminals first reached the office-cum")
              doc.addField("coverage","patna");
              doc.addField("isSyndicated",1);
              doc.addField("createdDate",org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.addDays(date, -(index+101)));
              doc.addField("expiryDate","2061-12-17T03:06:13Z");
              doc.addField("language","en");
              doc.addField("version","1.0");
              doc.addField("ingestionDate","2011-12-16T21:36:28.296Z");
              doc.addField("ingestionDate_index","2011-12-17T03:06:00Z");
           
            
            System.out.println("Inserting document"+"   "+(j)+"   "+(index+1));
            
            try {
                solr.add(doc);
            } catch (SolrServerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            }
        
        try {
            UpdateResponse response = solr.commit();
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

When I insert data I get an error message something like this:-

> Inserting document   1   1
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=ibsfdjkhfb01] unknown field 'mongoid'

The error is encountered when i add fields in the document.
I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears that you have a field that is not in your schema. Try adding mongoid to your schema.xml and see if that helps.